# flutter Error: Execution failed for task ':native_pdf_renderer:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i am running my flutter project and i keep getting this error which i dont understand

```
: /Applications/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/native_pdf_renderer-4.0.1/android/src/main/kotlin/io/scer/native_pdf_renderer/NativePdfRendererPlugin.kt: (124, 29): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: /Applications/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/native_pdf_renderer-4.0.1/android/src/main/kotlin/io/scer/native_pdf_renderer/NativePdfRendererPlugin.kt: (138, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':native_pdf_renderer:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


Execution failed for task ':native_pdf_renderer:compileDebugKotlin'.
```

i have Flutter clean, Upgraded all package using(pub upgrade) still yet i am unable to solve this.

[image]

Comment: Can you please try `flutter run --verbose` to see the entire report? Alternatively, maybe you can also try build and run the gradle project in verbose mode since it looks like you are running it on an Android device/simulator

Comment: still thesame result, i am unable to run in verbose

Comment: OK, I see it's complaining about non-compatible types regarding null safety. Is native pdf renderer plugin something you make, or did you get it from somewhere else?

Comment: If you make it, please kindly share the relevant source code. If it's a third-party plugin, try to see if its latest version is a null-safety version.